# How to get exact data from react native firestore onSnapshot instead of data with arrays?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm calling onSnapshot in the useEffect and get the data when the specific document gets updated.
I can get the data but the data is returned as arrays with index.
For example,

```
{"createdAt": [7, 1595865535572], 
"lastMessage": [16, {"assetURL": [Array], "conversationId": [Array], "createdAt": [Array], "text": [Array]}], 
"observerUIDs": [10, [[Array], [Array]]], 
"observers": [10, [[Array], [Array]]]
```

Which in the api call, I have to get

```
{createdAt: 1595865535572, 
lastMessage: {"assetURL": "URL", "conversationId": "ID", "createdAt": 1242141204, "text": "HI}, observerUIDS: [{...}, {...}], ...}
```

In the useEffect call, I'm calling as

```
const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('Conversations')
      .where('observerUIDs', 'array-contains', 'uid')
      .onSnapshot(async documentSnapshot => {
documentSnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          var event = change._nativeData.doc.data;
          console.log(event);
})
```

Is there a way to get the exact data except for the array with index?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to show in more detail the document you're trying to read.  That debug log isn't very helpful.  A screenshot of the document might help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using
`documentSnapshot.docs[0]._data` instead

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use private data that's not exposed through an API with both `_nativeData` and `_data`.  This is a bad idea, since these implementation details can change over time and break your code.  You should use the public APIs.

Comment: The data I'm getting from above method is exactly same data I'm getting from api. I'm trying to reduce api calls possible since it doubles read if I call api inside onSnapshot

Comment: I think you're missing my point - it's a bad idea to use the private *undocumented* properties that begin with an underscore.  There are public properties and methods on the objects you're using right now that let you get access to all this data that are clearly spelled out in the documentation.  As I commented on your question, it would be helpful to see your document data more clearly to be able to know what best to do.